# Mockito Verify throws (Wanted but not invoked:) error every time, even if mocked method was called

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, android-room

I am mocking a Dao which is injected into a Repository class that I am testing.  When using the Mockito.verify(myDao) it works perfectly outside of the Repository class.  When I use it, it says the method was invoked once, exactly what I would expect.  Inside the repository class, however, it will always throw (Wanted but not invoked:)

What is strange is that Mockito.`when`() works perfectly fine in the Repository class, I know this because I filled it with Log.d statements.  The log.d statements show that the list passed with Mockito.`when`().thenreturn(myList) is being used.  This is in the repository.  However, even though I can clearly see this method has been invoked, Mockito.verify() still seems to believe it was never called.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class RepositoryTests {


@InjectMocks
private lateinit var repos: Repository

@Mock
lateinit var mockedDao : MomentDao

@get:Rule
val activityRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)

@get:Rule
val mockitoRule: MockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule()



@Test
fun hardDaoTest() {

    Mockito.`when`(mockedDao.findMomentsByBound(ArgumentMatchers.anyDouble(), ArgumentMatchers.anyDouble(),
        ArgumentMatchers.anyDouble(), ArgumentMatchers.anyDouble())).thenReturn(momentList)

    repos.queryMapMoments(LatLngBounds(LatLng(20.toDouble(), -40.toDouble()), LatLng(25.toDouble(), -30.toDouble())), zoom)

    Mockito.verify(mockedDao, times(1)).findMomentsByBound(
        ArgumentMatchers.anyDouble(), ArgumentMatchers.anyDouble(),
        ArgumentMatchers.anyDouble(), ArgumentMatchers.anyDouble())
```

}

So, the Mockito.when() works fine, and momentList is contained in the Repository just as expected.  Mockito.verify fails every time.

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

This was the error.

```
Wanted but not invoked:
mockedDao.findMomentsByBound(
<any double>,
<any double>,
<any double>,
<any double>
);
-> at
```

com.example.barrechat108.RepositoryTests.hardDaoTest(RepositoryTests.kt:147)
    Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

```
at
```

com.example.barrechat108.RepositoryTests.hardDaoTest(RepositoryTests.kt:147)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)